# SVG text looks different in Chrome compared to IE8

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, svg, raphael

I'm trying to stylize some text for my company's homepage. The text looks great in IE8 but does not look so good in Firefox or Chrome.

In firefox it looks like there is a few extra white pixels to the right of each character.
In chrome the effect is similar, but does not happen for all letters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="js/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.onload = function () {                                                       
            var paper = Raphael(10, 0, 600, 400);

            var lbl = paper.text(135, 40, "AaEeIiOoUuYy").attr( {
                "font" : '36px Franklin Gothic Medium, Helvetica, Arial',                       
                stroke : "#000",
                fill : '#ffffff',
                'font-weight' : 'bold',
                'text-anchor' : 'start',
                'stroke-opacity' : .9               
            });
            var lbl = paper.text(0, 90, "AaEeIiOoUuYy").attr( {
                "font" : '62px Franklin Gothic Medium, Helvetica, Arial',       
                stroke : "#000",
                fill : '#ffffff',       
                'font-weight' : 'bold',             
                'text-anchor' : 'start',
                'stroke-opacity' : .9
            });
        }       
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #page
        {           
            background: #000;
            width:100%;         
            height: 600px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="page">   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are images showing the issue :
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oXBH.jpg)
[IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krbc2.jpg)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9zv.jpg)
I'm using Raphael 1.5.2. Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm also open to any other cross-browser solution that allows me to display a specific font with a thin black outline (stroke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching raphael and using font-shadow for firefox/chrome, and a slight Glow filter for IE. This fixes my problem for all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the stroke colour to the same as the fill, it'll hide the slight rendering fault.

You should be aware that IE uses it's own vector rendering engine called VML rather than SVG. Raphael does a great job of hiding most of the differences for you but not all. The VML renderer has a number of bugs, that worst of which for your use is that IE7 will ignore the specified font family and always use Arial.

Comment: The problem is this text is going to be used on an image background, so the stroke is really needed to help the text stand out.

Comment: You can also use stroke-width to widen it, and cover the fill color that way.

Comment: I haven't used SVG in a while but the code doesn't even look correct for SVG. Doesn't the namespace have to be declared? Not sure in HTML5 but that doesn't work in IE anyway. So, perhaps, that's why it doesn't look good in the modern browsers because it's not proper SVG in the first place!